# Prove that there are no integer solutions to the equation below

Tags: integers

This is the equation for which I've to show that there are no integer solutions:

$5x^2-2y^2=4$

Any approach works! I’m just confused because I see some people approach by showing hyperbolas and some approach with a more modular approach.

Comment: So you need to choose your $n$ carefully. Since one of the coefficients is $5$, $n=5$ can be tried : does $y^2=-2$ has a solution modulo $5$?

Comment: Also the hyperbolic approach, well you must tell us where you saw it, and we can tell you when it applies.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's the converse. If there's no solution in mod $n$, then there's no solutions in integers. Because $x^2=2$ doesn't have integer solutions, but $x^2\equiv2\pmod 7$ has solution $x\equiv3,4$.

Since $5$ is one of the coefficients, it might be worth to try modulo $5$, because the $x^2$ is destroyed. Then $-y^2\equiv2\pmod5$, or $y^2\equiv3\pmod5$. However, all quadratic residues (values $n$ such that there's an $a$ for $a^2\equiv n$) in mod $5$ are $0,1,4$. Then there's no solution in integers.

Answer (score 1):

Modulo $5$ the number  $-y^2$ is $0,1,-1$ so $5x^2-y^2$ cannot be $2\mod 5$.